# Trouble for login using php ciode

Tags: php

I have two different tables from my database mywebsite.
Table login and table studentlogin. Can you suggest me how to make a login php code page which retrieve data from both table.

```
    <?php 
     if (!isset($_POST["username"]))


     {

     header('Location: login.html');
       }
      if (!isset($_POST["password"]))
      {

      header('Location: login.php');
      }

     else
       {
    session_start();    
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
    include ("db_connect.php"); 
    $select = "SELECT * from login and studentlogin where username = '$username' and password = '$password'";

      $rows = mysql_query("$select");

    if (mysql_num_rows($rows)<1){

            mysql_close($con);

    header("location: http://localhost/Mywebsite/wrong.html");

       }
    else
       { 


        while($query = mysql_fetch_array($rows)) {

            $adm = $query['username'];


           $check = substr($adm, 0, 3);
             if ($check == 'adm')
                {
```

Comment: if ($check == 'adm')
     {
        
     header('Location: index.php');
     
     }
     else 
      {
      header('Location: http://localhost/Mywebsite/student/index.php');
      }  
    
    
    
    }
    
    
    
  }         
 
}

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: im very new to php could provide me a sample code plz...

Comment: Uh....there is plenty of sample code in the links in the comments.

Comment: Don't set the session if the values aren't verified. Why are there 2 login tables?

Comment: If you are starting now your project, I suggest you to revise table structure: only one table with additional “class” field (student, adm, etc...). To start with modern MySQL driver you can refer to [this tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderDate
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Customers
ON Orders.CustomerID=Customers.CustomerID;
```

and read about join query and table relations.